# Regex replace with negative look ahead in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to delete the single quotes surrounding regular text. For example, given the list:

```
alist = ["'ABC'", '(-inf-0.5]', '(4800-20800]', "'\\'(4.5-inf)\\''", "'\\'(2.75-3.25]\\''"]
```

I would like to turn "'ABC'" into "ABC", but keep other quotes, that is:

```
alist = ["ABC", '(-inf-0.5]', '(4800-20800]', "'\\'(4.5-inf)\\''", "'\\'(2.75-3.25]\\''"]
```

I tried to use look-head as below:

```
fixRepeatedQuotes = lambda text: re.sub(r'(?<!\\\'?)\'(?!\\)', r'', text)
print [fixRepeatedQuotes(str) for str in alist]
```

but received error message:

```
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern.
```

Any other workaround? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you want `"'\\'(4.5-inf)\\''"` to yield?

Comment: Alright, so what is your definition of "regular text"? Alphanumeric A-Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try should work:**

```
result = re.sub("""(?s)(?:')([^'"]+)(?:')""", r"\1", subject)
```

**explanation**

```
"""
(?:         # Match the regular expression below
   '           # Match the character “'” literally (but the ? makes it a non-capturing group)
)
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^'"]       # Match a single character NOT present in the list “'"” from this character class (aka any character matches except a single and double quote)
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?:         # Match the regular expression below
   '           # Match the character “'” literally (but the ? makes it a non-capturing group)
)
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub` accepts a function as the replace text. Therefore,

```
re.sub(r"'([A-Za-z]+)'", lambda match: match.group(), "'ABC'")
```

yields

```
"ABC"
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, it solves my problem. It should be match.group(1).

Comment: @Eric: I think you're confusing `.group()` with `groups()`. (In reference to the above comment.)